# Why std::vector<T>.resize() requires T has default ctor(with no parameter)?

Tags: c++, vector, constructor, resize, default

I've got test code snippet:

```
#include<vector>
using namespace std;
struct My {
    My(int i) {}
    My(My&&) noexcept {}
    My(const My&) {}
};
int main() {
    vector<My> vm;
    vm.emplace_back(My(3));
    vm.resize(3); // compile error
    return 0;
}
```

g++ compile with error:

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/9/vector:65,
                 from defaultCtor.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_construct.h: In instantiation of ‘void std::_Construct(_T1*, _Args&& ...) [with _T1 = My; _Args = {}]’:
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:545:18:   required from ‘static _ForwardIterator std::__uninitialized_default_n_1<_TrivialValueType>::__uninit_default_n(_ForwardIterator, _Size) [with _ForwardIterator = My*; _Size = long unsig ned int; bool _TrivialValueType = false]’
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:601:20:   required from ‘_ForwardIterator std::__uninitialized_default_n(_ForwardIterator, _Size) [with _ForwardIterator = My*; _Size = long unsigned int]’
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:663:44:   required from ‘_ForwardIterator std::__uninitialized_default_n_a(_ForwardIterator, _Size, std::allocator<_Tp>&) [with _ForwardIterator = My*; _Size = long unsigned int; _Tp = My]’
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/vector.tcc:627:35:   required from ‘void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::_M_default_append(std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::size_type) [with _Tp = My; _Alloc = std::allocator<My>; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::size_type = long unsi gned int]’
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_vector.h:937:4:   required from ‘void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::resize(std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::size_type) [with _Tp = My; _Alloc = std::allocator<My>; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::size_type = long unsigned int]
defaultCtor.cpp:12:16:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_construct.h:75:7: error: no matching function for call to ‘My::My()’
   75 |     { ::new(static_cast<void*>(__p)) _T1(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...); }
      |       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
defaultCtor.cpp:6:5: note: candidate: ‘My::My(const My&)’
    6 |     My(const My&) {}
      |     ^~
defaultCtor.cpp:6:5: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
defaultCtor.cpp:5:5: note: candidate: ‘My::My(My&&)’
    5 |     My(My&&) {}
      |     ^~
defaultCtor.cpp:5:5: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
defaultCtor.cpp:4:5: note: candidate: ‘My::My(int)’
    4 |     My(int i) {}
      |     ^~
```

If resize() insolves reallocation of memory and moving objects, as I already defined `My(My&&)`: internal implementation of STL shouldn't fail our client code, right?

What's the semantic rule behind this? If resize() requires default ctor, then it actually creates some empty `My` objects, which might harm client code design: some client code base forbids trivial default ctors, by making it `private` and `=default` or even `deleted`.

So STL resize() function actually breaks this kind of coding rule, any workaround for it?

Comment: Yes, `resize` will create new objects if it increases the vector size. Why do you want to resize the vector? What should be the state of the two additional objects? Maybe you really only want to reserve memory with `.reserve` instead? Also, you are using `emplace_back` wrong. The whole point of using `emplace_back` instead of `push_back` is that you can give the _constructor arguments_ instead of the object itself to `emplace_back`, so that the object is directly constructed in-place from the arguments instead of being copied/moved. So you should be writing `vm.emplace_back(3)` instead.

Comment: When you resize, any added elements need to be initialised somehow.  If you specify a value to initialise with, that value will be copied.   If you do NOT provide a value to initialise with then `resize()` must default to something - and, for class types, that means using a constructor that accepts no argument (default construction).

Comment: Regarding _"STL resize() function actually breaks this kind of coding rule"_ -- no, it _enforces_ it. Your rule says that nobody can default-construct an instance of this class. And so you should not be able to get default-constructed objects by resizing a vector. I concur with the presumption in the first comment that suggests you probably wanted to _reserve_ storage.

Comment: A resize moves objects in the vector to a new, freshly allocated heap location. But your move and copy ctors are non-functional. Why do you want them not to do what they are supposed to do? The defaults should work just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rule doesn't break your class semantics -- it actually enforces them. When you resize a vector, any new elements added are default-constructed. Since that is not allowed, then you may not resize a vector this way.

Instead, you can use another overload of `resize` that accepts a value to initialize new elements with. See [reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize):

```
void resize( size_type count, const value_type& value );
```

This relies on the ability to copy values. You defined a copy constructor already and you just need an assignment operator to complete that picture. The default assignment operator will use the copy constructor, but you must explicitly make it available. In C++11 that's easy. In older language editions, you must implement it explicitly.

So, this will compile:

```
#include<vector>

using namespace std;

struct My {
    My(int i) {}
    My(My&&) noexcept {}
    My(const My&) {}
    My& operator=(const My&) = default;
};

int main() {
    vector<My> vm;
    vm.emplace_back(My(3));
    vm.resize(3, My(0));
    return 0;
}
```

In the above, any additional elements will be initialized with a copy of `My(0)`. We have not broken the semantics of your design, because it explicitly allows copies.

It should be mentioned that if you are allowing such values as `My(0)` (or whatever) to represent some kind of "empty" or "unused" state, then one wonders why you don't simply make the `int` parameter in the constructor optional (default to some value) in the first place.

```
My(int i = 0) {}
```

That effectively means you *can* default-construct the object and would not run into this problem in the first place.

Comment: You should mention `reserve`, which just allocates space for new elements without initializing them and therefor does not need a default constructor or default value. Doing `vector<My> vm; vm.reserve(3);` would avoid copying while filling the vector.

Answer (score 3):

It is required, otherwise it can not increase a vector size without default values.

Workaround is `std::unique_ptr<T>`, or `std::optional<T>`, or use another overloaded `std::vector<T>::resize` with the second parameter for a default `T`.

```
vm.resize(3, My(0));
```